# OfficeDevPnP.Core AuthenticationManager GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext is throwing error

Tags: sharepoint-addin, pnp

I am thinking of trying OfficeDevPnp Core dll for CSOM operations in my current project. I'm doing a POC to check if add-in only context works for SharePoint 2013 on-premises.

I have checked `GetNetworkCredentialAuthenticatedContext` method and it worked. But the method that gets add-in only context is not working and it throws error that object reference set to null.

I want to understand if this method works for On-Premises. Got this doubt because it expects appsecret as a parameter and as I know appsecret (Client Secret) is not necessary for High Trust add-ins. I have registered an add-in from appregnew.aspx. And provided it Add-in only permissions. But my console job where I get the add-in only context fails.

Can someone let me know what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are aboslutely right about ClientSecret is not necessary for high-trust apps.
Unfortunately `GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext` works only with low-trust apps and uses AzureACS in order to obtain access token. That's why it doesn't work for you.
Hopefully you have two options:

1. Configure low-trust for on-premise farm (I would say complicated scenario, requires Office 365 subscription and a lot of configuration work)
2. Use `TokenHelper.GetS2SAccessTokenWithWindowsIdentity` passing `null` as second parameter. `TokenHelper` is internal inside PnP, but you can add `AppForSharePointWebToolkit` nuget package and nuget will add `TokenHelper.cs` in your project. `TokenHelper.GetS2SAccessTokenWithWindowsIdentity(siteUrl, null)` does exactly what you need, but it's also required to have config updated with appropriate values (`ClientId`, `ClientSigningCertificatePath`, `ClientSigningCertificatePassword`, `IssuerId`)

Comment: Hey , I know that TokenHelper class and it's method. I have used it in my previous project to get add-in only client context. In the current project, I am trying OfficeDevPnP.Core and want to use only the methods given by PnP Core dll instead of directly accessing TokenHelper or SharePointContext classes. I'm more interested to know how to make the GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext method from PnP work in on-Premises case.

Comment: There are no methods for obtaining app only token with high-trust in current version of `AuthenticationManager`. So the answer is you can't. Most of the other methods, if you look at the [code here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/AuthenticationManager.cs#L571) are simply wrappers around `TokenHelper`.

Comment: So the approach I should take is call the Method from SharePointContext or TokenHelper to get addin only context and on the context object I can still use the PnP extension methods.

Comment: True, it doesn't matter how you obtained context object, you can use any of the PnP extensions on it.

Comment: I've used TokenHelper method to obtain add-in only context. And it worked well. I hope soon PnP team will make the method work for on-prem as well.